# Placeholders in Python: placing multiple names in an array

Tags: python

I am a beginner in python and learning "Learn Python: The Complete Python Programming Course" using Udemy. I downloaded Python 3.8. All things were good until I reached placeholders:

```
for i in arr.
Print(sen%(“i”))
```

I just want to use the function of placeholders in python and complete the task by placing multiple names in an array. I cannot type any of this. May I know why?

I am stuck and can't move ahead in the learning of the course.

[image: My work]

[image: As the course says]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Well as the error shows, you have a syntax error. That is because a `for` needs to end with a colon `:` and not a dot `.`. Also, using the `%` placeholders is very old and outdated and you should be using more "modern" techniques such as the `format` string method, or `f-strings`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
for i in arr:
    print(sen%(i))
```

That is, replace `arr.` to `arr:`

Comment: for i in arr:
... print(sen%(i))
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    print(sen%(i))
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: Now try. Make sure print is intended by 4 spaces. Better type manually the solution rather than copying it. After the colen in first line, when you press enter, it automatically intents and then you don't need to manually intend

Comment: If you check the second picture you have in the question carefully, you see that after arr : (colon) is used. You mistakingly so it as a . (full stop)

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit finicky and will throw an error if the statement isn't lined up correctly, if you hit return in the wrong spot, or put a space where there shouldn't be one.

1. As @Joshua Varghese suggested, first change arr. to arr:
2. Make sure there is no space in `arr:print(sen%(i))`
3. Put your curser just before `print(sen%(i))`, and hit return. (This will put your print statement on the next line with the correct spacing).
4. To have your program execute and iterate through the array of names, you need to have your curser on the next line, the line following `print(sen%(i))`, then hit return.

Note: using **python 3.9.2** on Mac OS